# Temporal Table Oracle Vs SQL Server , How to and history

Tags: oracle, temporal-tables

The following code denotes both Sql Server and Oracle both to create a temporal Solution.
For Oracle the following [article](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/docs/vldbg/temporalvalid/temporal-validity-example.html) is the basis.

```
---/// Temporal Table SQL Server ///---

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee(
   EMPNO   INT
  ,ENAME    VARCHAR(10)
  ,JOB      VARCHAR(9)
  ,MGR      INT
  ,HIREDATE DATE
  ,SAL      NUMERIC(7,2)
  ,COMM     NUMERIC(7,2)
  ,DEPTNO   INT
   CONSTRAINT EMP_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO)
  ,SysStartTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
  ,SysEndTime datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
  ,PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)) 
  WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.EmployeeHistory, DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON));

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO)values
(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, '02-MAR-1970', 8000, NULL, 20),
(7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '20-MAR-1971', 1600, 3000, 30),
(7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '07-FEB-1983', 1250, 5000, 30),
(7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839, '02-JUN-1961', 2975, 50000, 20),
(7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '28-FEB-1971', 1250, 14000, 30),
(7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839, '01-JAN-1988', 2850, 12000, 30),
(7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839, '09-APR-1971', 2450, 13000, 10),
(7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566, '09-DEC-1982', 3000, 1200, 20),
(7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, '17-JUL-1971', 5000, 1456, 10),
(7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '08-AUG-1971', 1500, 0, 30),
(7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788, '12-MAR-1973', 1100, 0, 20),
(7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698, '03-NOV-1971', 950, 0, 30),
(7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566, '04-MAR-1961', 3000, 0, 20),
(7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782, '21-JAN-1972', 1300, 0, 10)


SELECT * FROM Employee
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory --Would return 0 rows.


UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET SAL=SAL+2000
WHERE EMPNO=7369
 
SELECT * FROM Employee
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory --Would return 1 rows. prior to change.


UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET SAL=SAL+2000
WHERE EMPNO=7369

SELECT * FROM Employee
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory --Would return 2 rows. prior to change.

--if you want to check the list of changes which have happend you could simply query the history table .
SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory WHERE EMPNO = 7396 
union all
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EMPNO = 7396 
ORDER BY SysStartTime DESC

---/// Temporal Table Oracle ///---
---/// ORACLE (ASSUME AUTOCOMMIT IS ON).  ///---

CREATE TABLESPACE STATIC_DATA  DATAFILE 'static_data.dbf' SIZE 10m AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 1g  ;
CREATE TABLESPACE STATIC_ARCHIVE  DATAFILE 'static_archive.dbf'  SIZE 10m AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 1g ;
CREATE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE STATIC_ARCHVIE_FB TABLESPACE STATIC_ARCHIVE QUOTA 1 G  RETENTION 7 YEAR; --7 YEARS RETENTION.


CREATE TABLE TEST.Employee(
   EMPNO   INT
  ,ENAME    VARCHAR(10)
  ,JOB      VARCHAR(9)
  ,MGR      INT
  ,HIREDATE DATE
  ,SAL      NUMERIC(7,2)
  ,COMM     NUMERIC(7,2)
  ,DEPTNO   INT
   CONSTRAINT EMP_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO)
)
  TABLESPACE STATIC_DATA;
 
  ALTER TABLE TEST.Employee ADD PERIOD FOR History;
  ALTER TABLE TEST.Employee FLASHBACK ARCHIVE STATIC_ARCHVIE_FB;


 INSERT INTO TEST.Employee (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO)values
(7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, '02-MAR-1970', 8000, NULL, 20),
(7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '20-MAR-1971', 1600, 3000, 30),
(7521, 'WARD', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '07-FEB-1983', 1250, 5000, 30),
(7566, 'JONES', 'MANAGER', 7839, '02-JUN-1961', 2975, 50000, 20),
(7654, 'MARTIN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '28-FEB-1971', 1250, 14000, 30),
(7698, 'BLAKE', 'MANAGER', 7839, '01-JAN-1988', 2850, 12000, 30),
(7782, 'CLARK', 'MANAGER', 7839, '09-APR-1971', 2450, 13000, 10),
(7788, 'SCOTT', 'ANALYST', 7566, '09-DEC-1982', 3000, 1200, 20),
(7839, 'KING', 'PRESIDENT', NULL, '17-JUL-1971', 5000, 1456, 10),
(7844, 'TURNER', 'SALESMAN', 7698, '08-AUG-1971', 1500, 0, 30),
(7876, 'ADAMS', 'CLERK', 7788, '12-MAR-1973', 1100, 0, 20),
(7900, 'JAMES', 'CLERK', 7698, '03-NOV-1971', 950, 0, 30),
(7902, 'FORD', 'ANALYST', 7566, '04-MAR-1961', 3000, 0, 20),
(7934, 'MILLER', 'CLERK', 7782, '21-JAN-1972', 1300, 0, 10)

SELECT * FROM TEST.Employee
-- ??? any Equivalent in Oracle for this -> SELECT * FROM EmployeeHistory .

UPDATE TEST.Employee
SET SAL=SAL+2000
WHERE EMPNO=7369

UPDATE TEST.Employee
SET SAL=SAL+1000
WHERE EMPNO != 7369
 
SELECT * FROM TEST.Employee --//Would return the current dataset.
SELECT employee_id FROM TEST.Employee AS OF PERIOD FOR  history 'Date_to_be_replaced_with_Scn_in_your_database'
--// The above would retun the data before update all records.
```

Question 1: I can see the changes only at a point in time. If the record is updated multiple times in a day how do i get the changes to show the history?

Question 2: Is flashback not a temporary table and may get purged when certain events occur in db?

I tried querying between specific date ranges but the query is only point in time and would not give me all the history of the records like sql server.

I will if this does not work need to write trigger on each static table and insert it to my own history table. Trying to avoid triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking at a complete history, then flashback data archive is probably the solution you want to be exploring, combined with the VERSIONS BETWEEN clause.  For example, for a (single) row in the DEPT table you could write

```
SQL> SELECT deptno, dname,
  2       VERSIONS_STARTTIME
  3      ,VERSIONS_XID
  4      ,VERSIONS_OPERATION
  5  FROM dept
  6  VERSIONS BETWEEN TIMESTAMP
  7         SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20:00' MINUTE TO SECOND
  8     AND SYSTIMESTAMP
  9  WHERE deptno = 10;

   DEPTNO DNAME          VERSIONS_STARTTIME     VERSIONS_XID     V
--------- -------------- ---------------------- ---------------- -
       10 UNKNOWN        06-MAY-20 11.53.45 PM  0200100060040000 U
       10 MONEY GRABBERS 06-MAY-20 11.53.36 PM  0600050065040000 U
       10 FINANCE        06-MAY-20 11.53.24 PM  09000D001D050000 U
       10 BEAN COUNTERS  06-MAY-20 11.53.12 PM  01001A00EA030000 U
       10 ACCOUNTING
```

Here's a video explaining the "behind the scenes" on FDA

https://youtu.be/qIs2UPIodQg

and if you do end up going down the trigger route, I've got an implementation that lets you auto-generate them for tables here

https://github.com/connormcd/audit_utility